# Change default home folder location to a NAS in Linux Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: directory, home-directory

I am trying to achieve two goals on a new Linux Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Windows 2012 R2 environment:
1. I would like to change the default home folder for the Linux users to point to a new NAS storage, how do I do that? I would like to make sure people cannot see each others home folders, and that they have a 1TB quota each. Can this be done from Linux?
2. Can I auto map a network drive for all users login in to the Linux to another NAS folder?
3. I have just linked the Linux to the Windows 2012 AD, so user accounts from the Windows can access the Linux, is this something I can set from the GPO?

Comment: dosnt mounting the NAS storage to /home solve the problem? One has to edit the /etc/fstab and put an entry of the IP address of the NAS storage. Ofcourse, you have to wait till the network is up, before mounting the drive. You can check here for a similiar problem : https://askubuntu.com/questions/580567/how-can-i-mount-an-nfs-drive-via-fstab

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking linux Group policy which can be controlled from Windows 2012 R2 server. If so, then IMHO, no free solution is available yet.

Some commercial solution is available.
http://www.beyondtrust.com/Products/...vicesADBridge/

http://www.centrify.com/directcontrol/grouppolicy.asp

cheers
--harry

Comment: This answer looks pretty spammy to me...